# Charles not receiving requests once forticlientssl vpn is on device

Tags: android, request, response, vpn, charles-proxy

I'm trying to get requests on charles from a android device. I'm able to get the response without
forticlientssl vpn is connected on phone. Once connected it just doesn't receive any requests on charles. i have spent two days already to find solution on this website but nothing have worked so far. Can someone give any suggestion on how to connect my device with it.

I'm using charles 4.6.1 and forticlientssl version 6.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution for the same and we tried whitening our ip  but that's not a reliable solution because it gets changed. I set up the charles on android emulator and recorded traffic on charles. I followed the following steps

1. Connect with vpn on your system.
   Open wifi settings within emulator (not from. Emulator setting)
2. Select wiki and add local ip address from advance options and default port 8888
3. Go got chrome in emulator and type http://chls.pro/ssl certificate will be downloaded.
4. To go setting again and search certificates.
5. Add the downloaded certificate in wifi/user certificate.
6. Check the requests traffic should be visible on charles.